# how to solve this problem in virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, virtual-environment

### i want to activate my models in my files, my code in terminal:

(env) PS C:\Users\MadYar\Desktop\code.py\learning_log> python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs

### error:

No changes detected in app 'learning_logs'

---

im using django to make a web application and i add models in my settings.py like that:

INSTALLED_APPS = [

```
'django.contrib.admin',

'django.contrib.auth',

'django.contrib.contenttypes',

'django.contrib.sessions',

'django.contrib.messages',

'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'learning_logs'
```

]

i dont know why it sais no changes detected in app 'learning_logs'

Comment: The message does not say that the learning_logs app was not found! It says that no changes have been found in the models of this learning_logs, which means that you have already executed this command and you should execute python manage.py migrate.(also you was added learning_logs app to settings.py not model!)

Answer (score 0):

1. add empty `__init__.py` in `learning_logs` folder.
2. check if you have any `models.py` in `learning_logs` folder.
3. add some models, which inherited from `django.models.Model`:

   from django import models

   class MyModel(models.Model):
   myfield = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
4. call `python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs`

if you see `No changes detected in app 'learning_logs'` again, try to read the tutorial, especially this part: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/